# Power generation from cosmic rays or particles?

Tags: solar-power

A random thought occurred to me:

Can we harness the energy from cosmic rays or particles or deadly radiation that's found (in space) just like we do for solar energy?

Comment: I think the answer is pretty yes, theoretically - but when you compare the energy density of that to the blowtorch that is solar radiation in space, it's probably not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not practical.

[Energy density of cosmic rays](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/306222/fulltext/): 1.8 eV/cm<sup>3</sup>, about 10<sup>-13</sup> J/m<sup>3</sup>.

Energy density of the Sun on Earth: [10<sup>3</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_irradiance) J/m<sup>3</sup>, or 16 orders of magnitude more.

Comment: If the energy density of cosmic rays would be sufficient for energy harvesting, manned space flight would be impossible and semiconductor electronics would be destroyed.

Comment: In the manner of a fresnel lens or parabolic mirror solar concentrator, you might use a giant magnetic field to concentrate cosmic rays (like a Bussard Ramjet collected hydrogen, in Larry Niven's stories).  But the power you'd harvest would still be a tiny fraction of the power you'd spend to maintain the field.